# Custom Action in Ribbon

Tags: 2013, ribbon, custom-actions

I have a working Custom button in the Ribbon but the image is giving me problems. No matter what I set ImageUrl to, it ignores it and if I check the DOM, the src is set to a default image:

src="/_layouts/15/1033/images/formatmap32x32.png"

```
  <CustomAction
       Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.StandardMenu"
       GroupId="ActionsMenu"
      Title="Generate Response"
      Rights="ManagePermissions"
      Description="Generate a draft response document."
      Sequence="10000"
      RegistrationType="List"
      RegistrationId="11002"
      ImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/generate32x32.png">
    <UrlAction     Url="~site/_layouts/15/ActionReport.aspx? List={ListId}"/>
  </CustomAction>
```

Why is my ImageUrl attribute being ignored. What is wrong with my markup?

Comment: Can you please check permission on your image icon? Please check size of your image icon whether it is 16*16 or not?

Comment: The image is deployed to the layouts folder where every authenticated user would have access. Is 16x16 a requirement? I thought 32x32 would work too

Comment: Duplicate http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/108684/sharepoint-2013-custom-action-menu-item-logo

Answer (score 2):

In CustomAction element, you are missing CommandUIExtension element which contains elements that extend the user interface.

```
<CommandUIExtension xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <!-- Define the (UI) button to be used for this custom action -->
    <CommandUIDefinitions>
        <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.ListForm.Display.Manage.Controls._children"> 
            <Button Id="{B511A716-54FF-4EAE-9CBE-EA02B51B626E}" 
                    Command="{4E2F5DC0-FE2C-4466-BB2D-3ED0D1917763}" 
                    Image32by32="~site/_layouts/15/images/generate32x32.png" 
                    Image16by16="~site/_layouts/15/images/generate16x16.png" 
                    Sequence="0" 
                    LabelText="Generate Response" 
                    Description="Generate a draft response document." 
                    TemplateAlias="o1" /> 
        </CommandUIDefinition>
    </CommandUIDefinitions>
</CommandUIExtension>
```

Set location attribute accordingly.

For more information, refer this [msdn link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh500259(v=office.14).aspx).

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work for me. I put your code within a CustomAction block but the same result. Just  a blue square where I want the image to be